# Adding missing timestamps to the start of a DataFrame and interpolating in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that is comprised of data downloaded from a server. I specify the time range of the data I want, and it returns a timestamp as well as the values I request.

These data are sampled at a higher cadence than what I need for the rest of my analysis. Typically, I want a one-minute cadence but the data is sampled every 2 to 3 seconds. Also, they often contain NaN values dispersed throughout. This is easy to fix - I can use `df.interpolate(method='linear').resample('min')` or something like that.

The problem arises when there is missing data at the start or end of the time ranges I specify. For example, I might want data from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 but the first available point within that interval is 00:11:52. It downloads data between 00:11:52 and 23:59:59, and since the timestamp values are also downloaded with the data, it doesn't include the start time I want.

What I would like to do is add the missing timestamps at the start of my dataframe and put NaN values in place of the missing data. Then I can go in, interpolate all the missing values, and average the data down to a one-minute cadence.

I've tried creating a list of timestamps that are missing, at a 1-minute cadence:

```
missing_time_range = pd.date_range(start=actual_start, end=imported_data['Time'][0], freq='min')
missing_df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': missing_time_range})
```

Then, I figured I just needed to concatenate these to the top of `imported_data`. Problem is, I don't know how to do this while also filling the data columns with NaN values. Let's say I have 2 columns called `data1, data2, data3`. I need the resulting dataframe to look like

```
index | timestamp | data1 | data2 | data3 |
-------------------------------------------
0     | 00:00:00  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |
1     | 00:01:00  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |
2     | 00:02:00  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |
...
11    | 00:11:00  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |
12    | 00:11:52  |  3.5  |  2.7  |  6.8  |
13    | 00:11:54  |  3.7  |  2.5  |  NaN  |
14    | 00:11:57  |  2.9  |  2.3  |  6.9  |
...
```

Edit: here is a working example of what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspedas
from pytplot import get_data

AtimeRange = ["2012-01-22/00:00:00","2012-01-23/23:59:59"]

artemis_fgm_import = pyspedas.themis.fgm(trange=AtimeRange, probe='b', time_clip=True, varnames='thb_fgs_gsm')

df_fgm = pd.DataFrame({'Time': get_data('thb_fgs_gsm')[0], 'BX_GSM': get_data('thb_fgs_gsm')[1][:, 0],
                           'BY_GSM': get_data('thb_fgs_gsm')[1][:, 1], 'BZ_GSM': get_data('thb_fgs_gsm')[1][:, 2]},
                          columns=['Time', 'BX_GSM', 'BY_GSM', 'BZ_GSM'])
df_fgm['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_fgm['Time'], unit='s')

missing_time_range = pd.date_range(start="2012-01-22/00:00:00", end=df_fgm['Time'][0], freq='min')
```

If you run this, you will get

```
0,2012-01-22 00:11:13.032623053,-0.023662,-6.803893,9.251984
1,2012-01-22 00:11:17.122667074,0.154417,-6.885548,9.220587
2,2012-01-22 00:11:21.212712049,0.351437,-6.708095,9.437492
3,2012-01-22 00:11:25.302756071,0.268127,-7.740106,9.104474
4,2012-01-22 00:11:29.392800093,0.616834,-7.077517,9.299590
5,2012-01-22 00:11:33.482844830,0.685583,-7.030550,9.129241
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataframe using `missing_date_range` as the index (giving it the name `Time` to match the existing dataframe time column, and then `concat` that to the existing data:

```py
missing_time_range = pd.date_range(
    start="2012-01-22/00:00:00",
    end=df_fgm['Time'][0],
    freq='min',
    name='Time'
)
out = (pd
    .concat([pd.DataFrame(index=missing_time_range).reset_index(), df_fgm])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
                             Time     data1     data2     data3
0             2012-01-22 00:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
1             2012-01-22 00:01:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
2             2012-01-22 00:02:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
3             2012-01-22 00:03:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
4             2012-01-22 00:04:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
5             2012-01-22 00:05:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
6             2012-01-22 00:06:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
7             2012-01-22 00:07:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
8             2012-01-22 00:08:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
9             2012-01-22 00:09:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
10            2012-01-22 00:10:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
11            2012-01-22 00:11:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
12  2012-01-22 00:11:13.032623053 -0.023662 -6.803893  9.251984
13  2012-01-22 00:11:17.122667074  0.154417 -6.885548  9.220587
14  2012-01-22 00:11:21.212712049  0.351437 -6.708095  9.437492
15  2012-01-22 00:11:25.302756071  0.268127 -7.740106  9.104474
16  2012-01-22 00:11:29.392800093  0.616834 -7.077517  9.299590
17  2012-01-22 00:11:33.482844830  0.685583 -7.030550  9.129241
```